# Cloud Firestore Storage - How to view billing breakdown?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I'm currently trying to investigate our costing for Firebase Cloud Firestore, and looking for a cost breakdown for "Cloud Firestore Storage"

This is what I see on the GCP console under "Billing" after grouping by SKU

[GCP Billing Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YauFD.png)

I'm wondering about a couple things here:

- Does this breakdown include storage buckets that were created for the firebase project?
- Is there any way to delve deeper on what this cost is coming from? Any way to see the total size of specific collections or collection groups?

Thanks so much!

I've tried a few things:

- viewing the AppEngine quotas--these were not informative
- viewing the Firebase Console--this only reports on reads/writes/deletes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The billing item (also know as a SKU) you're showing is "Cloud **Firestore** Storage", so this is the storage space that is being used by your data in the Firestore database - and does not include any storage used by the Cloud Storage buckets you use to store files.

---

While it is fully documentation [how the storage size is calculated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size), there unfortunately is no page in the dashboard where you can see the breakdown for your actual database.

It's a very valid (and common) feature request, and it the team is actively working on enhancing the so-called observability of Firestore. Id' recommend filing a feature request [with the Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com) to chime in and keep monitoring the [Firestore release notes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes) for relevant changes.

Comment: Thanks so much for this response! Do you know if there is some sort of work-around to compute the current size of a given collection or collectionGroup? I'm currently trying to reduce our storage costs, and trying to figure out where the largest culprits are.